# Trying to get Outlook Calendar events with Javascript, receiving a 401 Unauthorized error?

Tags: javascript, outlook, azure-active-directory, fetch

So I've got a custom .aspx page with pure JS/jQuery (so no Angular) that I upload to Sharepoint Online and can add as a webpart or iFrame to a site in Sharepoint Online. I want to display Outlook calendar events and I also use FullCalendar.io for the displaying part.

This also includes ADAL (Azure AD) security because it's needed for Outlook API.

So first I authenticate with Azure AD, get my acquired token and then pass that token to the function that builds my FullCalendar.io calendar on the page. This will try to get the Outlook Calendar events and display them nicely on the FullCalendar.

Here's the examples I followed:
https://codeatwork.wordpress.com/2017/04/16/using-outlook-rest-apis-in-sharepoint-online/
https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js
https://www.paitgroup.com/blog/display-events-from-an-outlook-calendar-in-sharepoint-using-office-365-apis

I've also added the permissions from link 1 to my Azure AD registered App in the Azure portal!

Here's my code:

```
<script>

  var $this = this;

  $(document).ready(function() {
    window.config = {
          tenantId: '{tenant}',
          clientId: '{clientId}',
          popUp: true,
          redirectUri: '{redirectURI}',
          endpoints: {
            "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/events":"https://outlook.office.com/",
          }
    };

    var authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(config);
    authenticationContext.handleWindowCallback();

    if (authenticationContext.getCachedUser()) {
      authenticationContext.acquireToken(config.clientId, function (errorDesc, token, error) {
        if (error) { //acquire token failure
          if (config.popUp) {
              // If using popup flows
              authenticationContext.acquireTokenPopup(config.clientId, null, null,  function (errorDesc, token, error) {});
          }
          else {
          // In this case the callback passed in the Authentication request constructor will be called.
              authenticationContext.acquireTokenRedirect(config.clientId, null, null);
          }
        }
        else {
          //acquired token successfully
          $this.DisplayEvents(token);
        }
      });
    }
    else {
        // Initiate login
        authenticationContext.login();
    }
  });

  function DisplayEvents(adalToken) {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
      header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
      },
      navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
      editable: true,
      eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
      events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
        var headers = new Headers();
        var bearerToken = "Bearer " + adalToken;
        headers.append('Authorization', bearerToken);
        var options = {
          method: 'GET',
          headers: headers,
          mode: 'no-cors'
        };
        var outlookEndpoint = 'https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/events?$select=Subject,Organizer,Start,End';

        fetch(outlookEndpoint, options)
          .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
          });
      }
    });
  }

</script>
```

As you can see, the token is passed to the "fetch" call in the events function of the fullCalendar() function. I've tried doing a normal ajax 'GET' call, but I get CORS errors. Same when I leave out "mode: 'no-cors'" from my options. Fetch is being done because of the github example I've linked above!

Now I'm receiving a 401 Unauthorized error and response that's filled with status:0 and body: null etc.

Anyone else has had this issue or can see what I'm doing wrong to make the authentication fail?

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your acquireToken method as below. Just replace "config.clientId" with "https://outlook.office.com/".

```
if (authContext.getCachedUser()) {
        authContext.acquireToken("https://outlook.office.com/", function (error, token) {
            if (error) { //acquire token failure
                if (config.popUp) {
                    // If using popup flows
                    authContext.acquireTokenPopup("https://outlook.office.com/", null, null, function (errorDesc, token, error) { });
                }
                else {
                    // In this case the callback passed in the Authentication request constructor will be called.
                    authContext.acquireTokenRedirect("https://outlook.office.com/", null, null);
                }
            }
            else {
                //acquired token successfully
                // alert('token success');
                DisplayEvents(token);
            }
        });
    }
    else {
        // Initiate login
        authContext.login();
    }
```

Besides, you can find the 401 error details by using Rest Client or postman. For example, this is the response in Rest Client.
[image]

Comment: Mhm indeed... I've gotten some new messages but in the end the 401 persists. I can see the error you've given me with more detail, thanks! What does this mean however? Because I've tried added permissions to EVERYTHING in the Exchange API connection, but it still didn't work. 

Should I be using Microsoft Graph instead?

Comment: After adding the permissions, did you click grant permission button?

Comment: You can decode your token to see if you have enough permission.

Comment: Yes, I clicked the grant permissions and it added the (admin?) permissions to all & I believe everyone in the tenant. I turned it back off after I tested it though.  

By decoding your token, you mean something like this https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/verify-access-token ? Then I shall try this next and keep you posted!

Comment: I've decoded my access token and can see following (what I assume are my permissions?): 

"scp": "Calendars.Read Calendars.Read.All Calendars.Read.Shared Calendars.ReadWrite Calendars.ReadWrite.All Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared Contacts.Read Contacts.Read.All Contacts.Read.Shared etc... So it seems I have quite a lot of permissions? 

Scp stands for delegated permissions it seems, "roles" stands for application permissions (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25185181/office365-ews-api-the-token-has-invalid-value-roles-for-the-claim-type) . Am I in the wrong here somewhere?

Comment: "scp": "Calendars.Read Mail.Read Tasks.Read", These three permission are enough to call that api.

Comment: And you need to use your tenant user to login in. For example, user@yourtenantname.onmicrosoft.com, and this account should be an email address.

Comment: Mhm I use an xxx@mycompany.com email address, is that the wrong one? Does it HAVE to be an existing onmicrosoft one?

Comment: @Tempuslight What is your tenant name? I mean your active directory full name, you need to use user@your active directory full name which is also an email address.

Comment: Thanks i'll have a look, but it's not an "onmicrosoft" one here

Comment: You are welcome. Then your company should map a custom domain here. Is it your companyName.com? If yes,user@yourCompany.com will be ok. By the way, have checked your permission? "Calendars.Read Mail.Read Tasks.Read"

Comment: The one we have should have sufficient permissions to do "things" on the azure environment and APIs etc, yeah I've got those permissions and granted them, but keep getting 401 :\